# Assigning an integer to a register

Tags: verilog

I am new to Verilog so I am having problems making conversions between different bases or types. More specifically I am trying to assign an integer to a 9 bit long register. The register will represent a signed integer in binary. I am trying to do something like this.

```
integer i = -10;
reg [8:0] r;

always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    r <= i;
  end
```

P.S. I am using Verilog with Xilinx ISE v12.4

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: This is wrong and not for trying to assign a negative integer to a register, but many other things. Please, fix the obvious mistakes and post a complete module.

Comment: I just want to know how to assign an integer to a register, forget about the negative.

Comment: It's not the sign which is bad in your code. It's everything else. To assign a value, be it constant, or held in a integer, or in another register, just assign it. For example, `integer i;` `reg [8:0] r;` `r <= i;`

Comment: @Pure: did you try doing it the way you propose?

Comment: @Qiu I used the equal sign "=" instead of "<=" and it worked. Can you suggest which to use when?

Comment: @Pure: check e.g. [this](http://www.asic-world.com/tidbits/blocking.html) page to find out.

Comment: @Pure read [Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding Styles That Kill!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Integers can be assigned to registers - and the other way around, ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36668354/2658159). But care needs to be taken so that the value isn't truncated.